# Azure blob sasToken “Signature did not match” (java)

Tags: java, azure, blob, sas-token

Hello I try to create a SAS to a blob on azure storage in java. 
I write the following code:

```
  public static String GSAS(String url, String signedstart, String signedexpiry) throws 
     Exception {

    String accountName = "taelearninguat2";
    String accountKey = "xxxx"; // Here I hide the passsword 

    String signedpermissions = "r";

    signedstart = "2020-02-18T08:49Z";
    signedexpiry = "2020-02-28T08:49Z";


    String canonicalizedResource = "/blob/" + accountName + "/resource/8a5dcc036edbba6a016ede49fec30000.jpg";

    String signedIP = "";
    String signedProtocol = "";
    String signedidentifier = "";
    String signedversion = "2015-04-05";
    String rscc = "";
    String responsecontent = "file; attachment";
    String rsce = "";
    String rscl = "";
    String rsct = "binary";

    String stringToSign =
            signedpermissions + "\n" +
                    signedstart + "\n" +
                    signedexpiry + "\n" +
                    canonicalizedResource + "\n" +
                    signedidentifier + "\n" +
                    signedIP + "\n" +
                    signedProtocol + "\n" +
                    signedversion + "\n" +
                    rscc + "\n" +
                    responsecontent + "\n" +
                    rsce + "\n" +
                    rscl + "\n" +
                    rsct;

   String sig = computeHmac256(stringToSign,Base64.getDecoder().decode(accountKey));

    StringBuffer param = new StringBuffer();
    param.append("?")
            .append("sv=").append(URLEncoder.encode(signedversion, "UTF-8")).append("&")
            .append("sr=").append(URLEncoder.encode("b", "UTF-8")).append("&")
            .append("sig=").append(URLEncoder.encode(sig, "UTF-8")).append("&")
            .append("st=").append(URLEncoder.encode(signedstart, "UTF-8")).append("&")
            .append("se=").append(URLEncoder.encode(signedexpiry, "UTF-8")).append("&")
            .append("sp=").append(URLEncoder.encode(signedpermissions, "UTF-8")).append("&")
            .append("rscd=").append(URLEncoder.encode(responsecontent, "UTF-8")).append("&")
            .append("rsct=").append(URLEncoder.encode(rsct, "UTF-8"));
    String sasURL = url + param.toString();
    return sasURL;
}





static String computeHmac256(String stringToSign, byte[] accountKey) throws Exception {
    try {
        /*
        We must get a new instance of the Mac calculator for each signature calculated because the instances are
        not threadsafe and there is some suggestion online that they may not even be safe for reuse, so we use a
        new one each time to be sure.
         */
        Mac hmacSha256 = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        hmacSha256.init(new SecretKeySpec(accountKey, "HmacSHA256"));
        byte[] utf8Bytes = stringToSign.getBytes("UTF-8");
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hmacSha256.doFinal(utf8Bytes));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Error(e);
    }
}
```

Suppose I have a picture which url is : https://taelearninguat2.blob.core.chinacloudapi.cn/resource/8a5dcc036edbba6a016ede49fec30000.jpg

so the stringToSign is :

```
r 
2020-02-18T08:49Z 
2020-02-28T08:49Z 
/blob/taelearninguat2/resource/8a5dcc036edbba6a016ede49fec30000.jpg



2015-04-05

file; attachment


binary
```

SAS url : https://taelearninguat2.blob.core.chinacloudapi.cn/resource/8a5dcc036edbba6a016ede49fec30000.jpg?sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=IbBspyUvIyOoxq7XRs7nQ3zHK%2BrlZzoen9jwSN%2B1Yfw%3D&st=2020-02-18T08%3A49Z&se=2020-02-28T08%3A49Z&sp=r&rscd=file%3B+attachment&rsct=binary

```
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was r 2020-02-18T08:49Z 2020-02-28T08:49Z /blob/taelearninguat2/resource/8a5dcc036edbba6a016ede49fec30000.jpg 2015-04-05 file; attachment</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
```

new update: 
alter the time params: 
signedstart = 2019-11-27
signedexpiry = 2019-12-04
then result to be :
Signature not valid in the specified time frame: Start [Wed, 27 Nov 2019 00:00:00 GMT] - Expiry [Wed, 04 Dec 2019 00:00:00 GMT] - Current [Thu, 20 Feb 2020 14:45:57 GMT]

but 
signedstart = 2020-02-19
signedexpiry = 2020-02-25
still signature not match

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing the following line of code:

```
byte[] shaSig = HMACSHA256(stringToSign, accountKey);
```

to

```
byte[] shaSig = HMACSHA256(stringToSign, Base64.getDecoder().decode(accountKey));
```

Basically your account key is a base64 encoded string you would need to decode it first.

You can also take a look at the code here as to how Azure SDK is doing the signing: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/1e2982e008aead0453e2295d41df5352c603fd34/storage/data-plane/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/SharedKeyCredentials.java#L213

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208221/discussion-on-answer-by-gaurav-mantri-azure-blob-sastoken-signature-did-not-mat).